# linq and stored procedures

Tags: linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to execute a stored procedure in LINQ. When run in SQL Server it returns several fields, mostly integer and float fields.  But when I call the stored procedure in LINQ, all it returns is 0.  Here is how I am calling the stored procedure :

```
var meterReadings = _database.MetricDataReport("20101127");
```

And here is the stored proc :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MetricDataReport]
@FormDate VARCHAR(8)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON  



/*Table To Hold Finished RecordSet*/
CREATE TABLE #OutputTable
(
    PkMetricMeterID INT,
    FkSiteID        INT,
    FourWeekReading FLOAT,
    LastWeekReading FLOAT,
    ThisWeekReading FLOAT,
    pkMeterID       INT,
    DecimalPlaces   INT

)

CREATE TABLE #WorkingTable
(
    PkMetricMeterID INT,
    FkSiteID        INT,
    FormDate        DATETIME,
    Reading         FLOAT,
    pkMeterID       INT,
    DecimalPlaces   INT
)   

-----------------------------------
---   Process Physical Meters   ---
-----------------------------------
    INSERT INTO #WorkingTable (PkMetricMeterID,FkSiteID,FormDate,Reading,pkMeterID,DecimalPlaces)
    SELECT
        luMetricMeters.PkMetricMeterID,
        LuMetricMeterList.FkSiteID,
        GetReadingsAndPriceLite.FormDate,
        GetReadingsAndPriceLite.CalculatedConsumption * GetReadingsAndPriceLite.ConversionFactor,
        luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID,            
        Meters.DecimalPlaces    
    FROM
        luMetricMeters 
    INNER JOIN
        luMetricMeterList ON luMetricMeterList.PkMetricMeterID = luMetricMeters.PkMetricMeterID
    INNER JOIN  
        GetReadingsAndPriceLite ON GetReadingsAndPriceLite.pkMeterID = luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    INNER JOIN
        Meters ON Meters.PkMeterID = luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    WHERE
        GetReadingsAndPriceLite.FormDate <= @FormDate AND GetReadingsAndPriceLite.FormDate >= DATEADD(wk,-4,@FormDate)
--------------------------------------------
---   Process Virtual Meters (NON KPI)   ---
--------------------------------------------

---Check To See If Meter Needs Updating
DECLARE @CurrentMeterID INT
DECLARE MeterCursor Cursor FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT 
        luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    FROM
        LuMetricMeters 
    INNER JOIN
        luMetricMeterList ON luMetricMeterList.PkMetricMeterID = luMetricMeters.PkMetricMeterID
    INNER JOIN
        VirtualMeterReadings ON VirtualMeterReadings.MeterID = luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    WHERE
        VirtualMeterReadings.UpdateFlag = 1
OPEN MeterCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MeterCursor INTO @CurrentMeterID
WHILE @@Fetch_Status=0
BEGIN
    EXEC UpdateVirtualReadings @CurrentMeterID
    FETCH NEXT FROM MeterCursor INTO @CurrentMeterID
END
CLOSE MeterCursor
DEALLOCATE MeterCursor


INSERT INTO #WorkingTable (PkMetricMeterID,FkSiteID,FormDate,Reading,pkMeterID,DecimalPlaces)
    SELECT
        luMetricMeters.PkMetricMeterID,
        LuMetricMeterList.FkSiteID,
        VirtualMeterReadings.FormDate,
        VirtualMeterReadings.Reading,
        LuMetricMeterList.pkMeterID,
        Meters.DecimalPlaces            
    FROM
        luMetricMeters 
    INNER JOIN
        luMetricMeterList ON luMetricMeterList.PkMetricMeterID = luMetricMeters.PkMetricMeterID
    INNER JOIN  
        VirtualMeterReadings ON VirtualMeterReadings.MeterID = luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    INNER JOIN
        Meters ON Meters.PkMeterID = luMetricMeterList.pkMeterID
    WHERE
        VirtualMeterReadings.FormDate <= @FormDate AND VirtualMeterReadings.FormDate >= DATEADD(wk,-4,@FormDate)

SET NOCOUNT OFF

SELECT DISTINCT
    [#WorkingTable].PkMetricMeterID,
    #WorkingTable.FkSiteID,
    ThisWeekReading = (SELECT TOP 1 Reading FROM #WorkingTable WorkingTable1 WHERE WorkingTable1.PkMetricMeterID = #WorkingTable.PkMetricMeterID AND [#WorkingTable].FkSiteID = [WorkingTable1].FkSiteID ANd workingTable1.FORMDATE = @FormDate),
    LastWeekReading = (SELECT TOP 1 Reading FROM #WorkingTable WorkingTable1 WHERE WorkingTable1.PkMetricMeterID = #WorkingTable.PkMetricMeterID AND [#WorkingTable].FkSiteID = [WorkingTable1].FkSiteID ANd workingTable1.FORMDATE = DATEADD(d,-7,@FormDate)),
    FourWeekReading = (SELECT AVG(Reading) FROM #WorkingTable WorkingTable1 WHERE WorkingTable1.PkMetricMeterID = #WorkingTable.PkMetricMeterID AND [#WorkingTable].FkSiteID = [WorkingTable1].FkSiteID),
    #WorkingTable.pkMeterID,
    #WorkingTable.DecimalPlaces
FROM
    [#WorkingTable]
ORDER BY    
    [#WorkingTable].PkMetricMeterID,
    [#WorkingTable].FkSiteID
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about this to see what the problem is, but you might want to first get this working using a far simpler stored proc. eg Something that just returns a simple list.

Also, take a look at [ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) on using Stored Procs with Linq to Sql.